# Call virtual method in constructor - better design

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I declared an ISerializable interface in java.

I basically have 2 methods: `serialize()`, and `deserialize(byte[] buffer)`.

```
public interface ISerializable{
    byte[] serialize();
    deserialize(byte[] buffer);
}
```

and here is an example of a class implementing this interface:

```
public class MySerializableClass implements ISerializable{   
    byte[] serialize(){bla bla}
    deserialize(byte[] buffer){bla bla};
}
```

Ideally, I would like the call to `deserailize` to be implicit. i.e. when calling the constructor `MySerializableClass(byte[] buffer)`, it would call the correct `deserialize` with the buffer passed. like that:

```
public abstract class AbstractSerializable {
    public abstract byte[] serialize();
    public abstract void deserialize(byte[] buffer);
    public AbstractSerializable (){}
    public AbstractSerializable (byte[] buffer){
        deserialize();
    }
}

public class MySerializableClass extends AbstractSerializable {
    byte[] serialize(){bla bla}
    deserialize(byte[] buffer){bla bla};
}
```

AFAIK it is problematic to call virtual methods within the constructor and this might end up with an undefined behavior.
so currently, I am doing the following:

```
MySerializableClass myClass = new MySerializableClass();
myClass.deserialize(buffer);
```

or by using a dedicated static method that is defined for each class that extends my interface (and basically just do the above 2 lines of code):

```
MySerializableClass myClass = MySerializableClass.CreateMySerializableClass(buffer);
```

My questions is: is there any elegant way to do that without the need to define a dedicated static method for each class implements ISerializable? Is there any design pattern that solves this issue?

**Note:** My serialization is unique so I need to write it on my own, and also for technical reasons I can only use very basic features of Java. ( no annotations,templaates metadata, etc.) so I need a very basic OOP solution.

Comment: Did you have look on how Java itself is doing that stuff with its own Serializable interface? You know you can manipulate how java-serialization handles your class, right?

Answer (score 2):

I find your solution elegant enough, what you're doing is a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), which is an elegant way to solve your problem. You can keep your constructor private, and always retrieve the objects through the factories

```
public class MySerializableClass extends AbstractSerializable {

    private MySerializableClass(){

    }

    public static MySerializableClass CreateMySerializableClass(final byte[] buffer){
        MySerializableClass result = new MySerializableClass();
        result.deserialize(buffer)
        return result;
    }

    byte[] serialize(){bla bla}

    deserialize(byte[] buffer){bla bla};
}
```

Comment: Good approach - Replace constructor with factory method (http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-constructor-with-factory-method)

Comment: I won't make the constructor private because sometimes I do want to create a new class without deserialization

Comment: @user844541 is for consistency, you can create another factory without serialization, actually the result is going to be the same, but since you can call the factories with the names that you want you can have a  better idea of what they do. So my suggestion is to keep it private and create another factory

Comment: @GuillermoMerino That's exactly what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

One another solution is you remove `no-argument constructor` so your **concrete class must** have  to initialize with argument constructor .

Comment: How will that solve the problem? and also sometimes I do want to create a new instance that is not created from byte array.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't pass byte arrays around when doing the serialization - instead I would use [java.io.DataOutput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html) and [java.io.DataInput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html). You could then declare the interface `ISerializable` like e.g. so:

```
public interface ISerializable{   
    void serialize(DataOutput out) throws IOException;
    void deserialize(DataInput in) throws IOException;
}
```

Then you could provide static utility methods, that are able to serialize and deserialize instances of `ISerializable` when provided with some DataOutput/DataInput. The static deserialize method could then also call a possible constructor, that accepts a DataInput as its only argument.

Here is a complete example code for this approach, that also includes a main method for testing the serialization:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;


public class SerializableTest {

    public interface ISerializable{   
        void serialize(DataOutput out) throws IOException;
        void deserialize(DataInput in) throws IOException;
    }

    /**
     * Writes the given ISerializable to the given DataOutput.
     */
    public static void writeSerializable(ISerializable s, DataOutput out) throws IOException{
        writeClass(out, s.getClass());
        s.serialize(out);
    }

    /**
     * Reads an ISerializable from the given DataInput.
     */
    public static ISerializable readSerializable(DataInput in, ClassLoader cl) throws IOException{
        ISerializable element = null;
        Class<?> c;
        try {
            c = readClass(in, cl);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
        try {
            try {
                // see if the class has a constructor that accepts a DataInput
                Constructor<?> constructor= c.getDeclaredConstructor(DataInput.class);
                constructor.setAccessible(true);
                return (ISerializable)constructor.newInstance(in);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                //ignore
            }
            element = (ISerializable) newInstance(c);
            element.deserialize(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Could not deserialize the class" + c.getName());
        }
        return element;

    }

    private static <T> T newInstance(Class<T> c) throws IOException {
        T element = null;
        Constructor<T> constructor;
        try {
            constructor = c.getDeclaredConstructor();
            if (!constructor.isAccessible()) {
                constructor.setAccessible(true);
            }
            element = constructor.newInstance();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException |
                IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | 
                InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new IOException(e);
        }
        return element;
    }

    private static void writeClass(DataOutput out, Class<?> c) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(c.getName());
    }

    private static Class<?> readClass(DataInput in, ClassLoader cl) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String name = in.readUTF();
        return cl.loadClass(name);
    }


    // some test classes for testing serialization in the main method

    public static class TestClass implements ISerializable{
        private String data;

        protected TestClass() {
            // ISerializable no argument constructor
            super();
        }

        public TestClass(String data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            out.writeUTF(data);
        }

        @Override
        public void deserialize(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            this.data = in.readUTF();
        }
    }

    public static class TestClass2 implements ISerializable{
        private final String data;

        protected TestClass2(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            // ISerializable DataInput constructor
            super();
            this.data = in.readUTF();
        }

        public TestClass2(String data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            out.writeUTF(data);
        }

        @Override
        public void deserialize(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    // tests serialization and deserialization of two test classes
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass t1 = new TestClass("TestClass 1");
        TestClass2 t2 = new TestClass2("TestClass 2");

        File file = new File("testfile");
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        DataOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out  = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
            writeSerializable(t1, out);
            writeSerializable(t2, out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }finally{
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }

        DataInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in  = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
            ClassLoader cl = SerializableTest.class.getClassLoader();
            TestClass loadedClass1 = (TestClass) readSerializable(in, cl);
            TestClass2 loadedClass2 = (TestClass2) readSerializable(in, cl);

            System.out.println("loadedClass1.data: " + loadedClass1.data);
            System.out.println("loadedClass2.data: " + loadedClass2.data);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } finally{
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you will have the memory overhead of storing the class name together with the data, when using the static methods. But you can still call the `serialize` and `deserialize` methods manually, if this is a problem.

Comment: the truth is that I don't even have access to IO, not to mention reflection or generics .. :( as I said I am working in a very primitive environment...

Comment: You do not need access to IO for this approach: `DataInput` and `DataOutput` are simple interfaces - you can provide your own implementations for them, that handle the writing/reading of the byte[] in the background.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you don't need to implement ISerializable interface with methods: serialize and deserialize. in any serializable class.
I think it would be better to have

```
interface ISerializer
{
    byte[] serialize(ISerializable serializable);
    ISerializable deserialize(byte[] buffer);
}
```

and have Serializer class which implements this ISerializer interface

ISerializable _ what to serialize or deserialize.

ISerializable will have methods, what serialization and deserialization need.
if serialization and deserialization don't need anything, it can be Object instead of ISerializable.

if you don't want casts after using deserialize method, this deserialize method can be generic:

> T deserialize<T>( byte[] buffer );